# What will be the recommended way to to Install Alfresco process service?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share

I wanted to install APS(Alfresco process service) for production environment.
for this installation, there are two ways.

1. By using Installer file
2. By using WAR files

What will be the best way for this, and what are the issues with other approach?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you [read the official docs for the two methods](http://docs.alfresco.com/process-services1.7/topics/installing_process_services.html)? Do you already have tomcat and a db installed and ready?

Comment: @Gagravarr Tomcat is not yet installed, only db is there

Comment: Also I read that official doc, but they mentioned that Installer approach is used for trial purpose. So I just want to understand the problems or issues, if we install APS on PROD using installer....

Answer (score 2):

For a Production installation you should deploy the war file into you own java container.
The reason for this is that it gives you a lot more flexibility in configuring the APS properties outside the war file.
While the installer is easy, it makes many assumptions about your environment.
Another option in case you werent aware is that APS is now available in the AWS environmen as a quick start application. This makes setting up a hosted environmenr quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks @Greg  Harley